# Why isn't my Sublime Text snippet responding to tab triggers?

Tags: code-snippets, sublimetext2

I just started using Sublime Text 2 but for some reason I can't get my snippets to work:

For example, here's a snippet that I'd like to use to set up my scripts for Handlebars.js:

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    </script>
]]></content>
<!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
<!-- <tabTrigger>handlebars</tabTrigger> -->
</snippet>
```

But when I'm in the editor and I type `handlebars`, and then Tab, all I see is `handlebars-1`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't this line `<!-- <tabTrigger>handlebars</tabTrigger> -->` be uncommented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to uncomment `<tabTrigger>`

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    </script>
]]></content>    
    <tabTrigger>handlebars</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```